# If the complex series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, show that there exists a positive number $A$ such that $|a_n| \leq A$ for all $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

**PROBLEM**

> If the complex series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, show that there exists a positive number $A$ such that $|a_n| \leq A$ for all $n$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since the complex series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$$ converges, then by the Ratio Test:
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1, \text{ for all } n.$$
This implies that
$$|a_{n+1}| < |a_n|$$
$$|a_n| < |a_{n-1}|$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
so that we have
$$\ldots < |a_{n+1}| < |a_n| < |a_{n-1}| < \ldots < |a_0|.$$
This implies that we can take
$$A := |a_0|.$$

**QUESTION**

> Is this proof correct?  If it is not correct, where is the error and how can it be mended?

Comment: It is not correct. It would need the $<$ replaced by $\leq$, the $1$ replaced by something a little more than 1, and the for all $n$ replaced by for all large $n$.

Comment: The ratio test just says that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ is eventually less than 1; it does not say that this holds for all $n$, but rather for all $n$ that are sufficiently large.  Thus the best you can say with your argument is that $|a_n| < |a_N|$ for all $n > N$, where $N$ is sufficiently large.  You still need to deal with the first $N$ terms.

Comment: I may be overly critical, but the use of the ratio test seems completely overkill to me. Basically, this follows from the (*much*) more elementary [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test), which states that if $\sum_n a_n$ converges then one must have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ (this theorem has a two-line proof). And then, well, every convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: I completely support this point of view.

Comment: Posting an answer now, thanks to Clement's hints in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$$
is convergent, then by the contrapositive of the Divergence Test,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 0.$$
This implies that the terms $\{a_n\}$ when considered as a sequence is convergent, which further means that there exists a positive number $A$ such that
$$|a_n| \leq A \text{ for all } n,$$
since every convergent sequence (of complex numbers) must be bounded.