# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{a_n}{z^n}}$ converges absolutely and uniformly in $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

**PROBLEM**

> Suppose that the complex series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges.  Let $r < 1$ and set $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < r\}$.
>
> > Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{a_n}{z^n}}$ converges absolutely and uniformly in $D$.

**MY FUTILE ATTEMPTS**

I know that I must somehow use the result(s) in this question: [If the complex series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, show that there exists a positive number $A$ such that $|a_n| \leq A$ for all $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2416697).

Also, the easiest way that I can think of to solve this problem is to use the following theorem:

**THEOREM** (*Weierstrass M-Test* or *Dominated Convergence Theorem*)

> > Given the series of functions $\ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{f_n}(z)}, z \in E$.  Suppose that $\{M_n\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that
> >     (i) $|{f_n}(z)| \leq M_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall z \in E$.  (ii) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{M_n}$ converges.  Then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{{f_n}(z)}$ converges **absolutely and uniformly** on $E$.

Of course I know that I need to set ${f_n}(z) = {a_n}{z^n}$.  Then ${f_n}(z)$ is a power series.  What I don't know is the sequence $\{M_n\}$.

**QUESTIONS**

**(1)** Is the Weierstrass M-Test indeed the best way to tackle this problem?  If so, what should be my $M_n$?

**(2)** If the answer to the first question in **(1)** is *NO*, how can I be able to solve this problem?

Comment: You have all the ingredients. You only need to realize that yo can pick $f_n(z)=a_n z^n$ and $M_n= Ar^n$ for the Weierstrass $M$-test, where $A$ is a bound for $(a_n)$.

Comment: Geez, thanks a bunch @SangchulLee!  I knew it was right before my eyes.  Just couldn't figure out the proper $M_n$ to use.  =)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: Archimedes: just a note that you can answer your own question if you want so this question no longer appears to be unanswered. On the other hand, if @SangchulLee submits his response, you will be able to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Clayton, okay!  Posting an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

We use the Weierstrass $M$-Test.

As hinted in the comments, we just need to pick ${f_n}(z) = {a_n}{z^n}$ and $M_n = Ar^n$, where $A$ is a bound for $\{a_n\}$ (by the result in [If the complex series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges, show that there exists a positive number $A$ such that $|a_n| \leq A$ for all $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2416697)).  Note that

(i) $\left|{f_n}(z)\right|=\left|{a_n}{z^n}\right|=|a_n||z^n| \leq A{r^n} = M_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall z \in D$.

(ii) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{M_n}$ converges by the Ratio Test.

Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{a_n}{z^n}}$ converges absolutely and uniformly in $D$.